# Data-Binding with Custom Dependency-Property of UserControl is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a `UserControl` with 2 custom `DependencyProperty`s (`ColumnsCount`, `RowsCount`):

```
public partial class CabinetGrid : UserControl
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnsCount", typeof (int), typeof (CabinetGrid));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowsCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RowsCount", typeof (int), typeof (CabinetGrid));

    public int ColumnsCount
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(ColumnsCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsCountProperty, value); }
    }
    public int RowsCount
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(RowsCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowsCountProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And here's the `DataBinding`:

```
<view:CabinetGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="GridRack" ColumnsCount="{Binding SelectedRoom.ColumnCount}" />
```

whereas the window's `DataContext` has a property `SelectedRoom` which invokes `PropertyChanged-Event`.
*Thru debugging, I got to know that the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` is set properly*.

However, when `SelectedRoom` has changed (=> I selected another item in a list), the `DependencyProperty` `ColumnsCount` of my `UserControl` is not updated.
I am very frustrated, as I already spent an entire day debugging through this unexpected shit, using tools like `XAMLSpy` and `WpfSpoon`.
Please, help.

---

EDIT:
Clemens already pointed out, that a breakpoint in the `CLR-Property` wrapping the `DependencyProperty` (`ColumnsCount`) is **not fired**. This is a major issue, since I have to call some methods on the change. I'm trying to use the `PropertyChangedCallback`, but am currently experiencing some errors.

Comment: thx but it doesnt work either.

Comment: "ColumnsCount of my UserControl is not updated". How exactly do you check that? Don't you see anything at all, or just no changed values? Is there a property change notification mechanism in place for the source property (i.e. `SelectedRoom`)?

Comment: @Clemens Sure, `SelectedRoom` ofc invokes the `PropertyChanged`-Event. I also made a `DataBinding` to `SelectedRoom` in another `UserControl`, and I can bind to any property of `SelectedRoom` properly (it does update)

Comment: And you haven't by accident (explicitly) set the DataContext of your CabinetGrid somewhere?

Comment: I check the change e.g. by using breakpoint's in the `DependencyProperty`s `Setter` as well as binding label-text to `SelectedRoom.ColumnCount`.  
No, the `DataContext` is (at least at the `Loaded`-Event) set properly to an    object with the property `SelectedRoom`.

Comment: The property setter isn't called (hence your breakpoint isn't hit) when the property is set by a Binding. WPF directly calls the SetValue method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get notified about value changes of a dependency property, you should specify a PropertyChangedCallback in the PropertyMetadata when you register the property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsCountProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ColumnsCount", typeof(int), typeof(CabinetGrid),
         new PropertyMetadata(OnColumnsCountPropertyChanged));

private static void OnColumnsCountPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     var cabinetGrid = (CabinetGrid)obj;

     // do something with the CabinetGrid instance
}
```

Comment: The callback, sure, raising the event, no. In the changed callback, get the datagrid context, and update the property there. Then you should end up in the setter, right? (just thinking out loud)

Comment: @TomVanSchaijk The callback would only be necessary if there would be anything to do. We don't know that, there might as well be an internal Binding. And "get the datagrid context, and update the property there" is wrong as well. You usually don't directly operate on a DataContext. That's what Bindings are for.

Comment: Yep, there's something to do when the property changes...sorry for not be that clear. After adding the callback, I get the error `The standard value type doesnt fit` (Standardwerttyp stimmt nicht mit der Eigenschaft `ColumnsCount` überein)

Comment: @ANewQuestionnaire If you copied this code it has an error - the value specified as the default property value in the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` constructor is `false` (a `bool`), whereas the property is of type `int`, so you should specify a proper default value (`0` for example) instead.

Comment: @ANewQuestionnaire I've fixed the answer so that it should give you a hint where to continue.

Comment: @Clemens: I want to draw `ColumnsCount` `Columns` and `RowsCount` `Rows`, since I'm not treating the `DataGrid` as a table, more like a grid where I can move cells (in context: Cell=Server-Cabinet, belonging to the `SelectedRoom`).
So each time a new room is selected, I have to represent the placement of it's server-cabinets inside the grid.

Comment: @ANewQuestionnaire That's an entirely different question.

Comment: @Clemens I just need a callback when one of my custom dependency properties changed, then I can do the other things manually (adding columns, binding to viewmodels)